# How to expand window/frame when button or checkbox is clicked in tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, checkbox, tkinter

I am using Tkinter for my python script. At current stage, gui looks ugly because of too many options/widgets in one screen. Not all of them are needed all the time and it can be divided into four parts. Hence my idea is to have them expand the frame (one frame for each part) with its options/widgets in the current window.

Is it possible in **tkinter** to **expand the window/frame when a button or a checkbox  is clicked?**

ps - I have tried opening each part in new window but this makes gui unnecessarily complicated.

Thanks!

Comment: Depending on which geometry manager you're using, why not just `grid` the widgets when you want them to appear and `grid_remove` them when you don't?  If you've set up the parent `Frame` that the widgets belong to, the `Frame` will expand and contract accordingly.

Comment: Thanks @Brionius. This did the job for me! It hides the frame beautifully; _however_ when the frame has to reappear, expansion is not a smooth process. It freezes a second in the middle of expansion process before the frame shows up.

Comment: _Addition to above comment:_ Expansion is smooth when I use 'grid_remove' for a single button widget but it is visually jarring and freezes a second when I use it for a frame containing 10-15 widgets. Any comment?

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe calling `root_window.update_idletasks()`  right after you re-`grid` all the widgets?  Worth a try.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Brionius! Unfortunately this doesn't do the trick. Actually same script works flawlessly in Windows but in mac there is that jarring and freezing. Guess it might have to do with OS.

Comment: Another thought - not sure if this will help - maybe you could force it to `update_idletasks` after every individual `grid`?  So you'd call `grid` then `update_idletasks` then `grid`, and so forth.  Worth a try, maybe.

Answer (score 0):

So, your gonna need to define what happens when the button is clicked-

```
def buttonClicked():
    root.geometry("350x300")
```

where root is the window and then on the button you will need to write -

```
btn = tkinter.Button(text = "Button", command=buttonClicked)
btn.pack
```

Hope that answers your question!